# How to query multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to achieve is to select the comments which are written only by my friends. I have the following tables.

Friends

```
id
my_user_id
friend_user_id
```

Comments

```
id
user_id
comment
```

This is how I did so far.

First find out who are my friends in the friends table:

```
mysql_query("SELECT friend_user_id FROM friends 
             WHERE my_user_id = $user_id ");
```

Then I selected the comments written only by my friends.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id = 'my_first_friends_id' 
             OR user_id = 'my_second_friends_id' ");
```

Now, this was the lame version, and it is very slow. I have millions of entries in the comments table.

What is the best solution for this problem? How to solve this in one query? And also very important to be fast.

Answer (score 3):

```
select c.id, c.user_id, c.comment
    from Friends f
        inner join Comments c
            on f.friend_user_id = c.user_id
    where f.my_user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out now. What is the c. and f. ?

Comment: @Maxxon those are table aliases, which allow you to refer to columns on those tables without repeatedly typing each table name.

Comment: Make sure friend_user_id and user_id are indexed, btw.  The c and f are table aliases, so you don't have to write "Friends" over and over again.

Comment: Thanks, I see You have changed c.* to c.id, c.user_id, c.comment. Will it work with c.* ?

Comment: @Maxxon: c and f are aliases for the Comments and Friends table. It's just a short-hand way of referring to the tables.

Comment: And how to add additional stuff? I mean: ORDER BY id DESC, or AND user_id != ''

Comment: @Maxxon: It will work with c.*, but that notation is strongly discouraged. Use specific column names as I've done instead.

Comment: @Maxxon: The AND is part of the WHERE, the ORDER BY comes after the WHERE.

Comment: @PMV, how to make the fields indexed? Do you know a source where I can learn it?

Comment: @Maxxon: At some point, you'll need to do some of this on your own or open a new question. Here's the link for [MySQL Create Index Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: I tested it but it does not do anything :( How should i get the values? How can i test if it works?

Comment: how to test if your query works?  you need to run it in some kind of query analyzer...how to tell if the index works?  check the EXPLAIN of your query...

Comment: I'm using PHP. I did the query, and then an mysql_fetch_array on the result and then print_r-d the result. But it says: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Comment: @Maxxon I'd open a new question, this info might be helpful to future stack overflow visitors.  Plus you'll probably get quicker responses.